# Display the values in sArticle in shopware 5

Tags: string, variables, shopware, shopware5

I would like to display the articles in my product export, which are stored as accessories for the articles.
For this I have now tried to display all the values that are in the sArticle. Unfortunately without success. In xml the whole thing looks like this:

`{if $sArticle} <debug>{$sArticle|@var_dump}</debug> {/if}`

I then get the following error message:

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 42 at column 591: Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 42 and p
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

If I remove the section again, the error is gone.
How do I see all the values associated with the sArticle?
Thanks a lot

I have as explained in the above section to get the values via the  tag